# How to scan network for devices, using C Obj C or Swift

Tags: objective-c, c, networking, swift, ip

I have a server running on a Raspberry Pi and a client running on my Mac and iPhone (soon Apple Watch). I would like to connect to my server automatically without finding the Raspberry pi's Ip-address.

Is there a way to lookup all the devices on the network, and select by Mac-address, name or something else? I know that the first 3 bytes of the mac-address is the same for all Pies. (B8:27:EB) Maby i can use that information.

I have been looking for a solution for this issue a while but i can't seem to find one.

Comment: This is an interesting question.. and I would also like to see an answer to this. Have you investigated Libraries like AFNetworking? Some investigating on GitHub might even revel projects that forked AFNetworking to abstract it even more to ease noobs like us into the this kind of functionality. :) Also ... check out Cocoapods. http://cocoapods.org/; https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=afnetworking

Answer (score 3):

## Zeroconf (aka Bonjour)

IMO, the best way to do this is to have your Raspberry Pi advertise itself on the network using [Zeroconf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-configuration_networking) (aka. Bonjour).

On the Raspberry Pi, install [avahi-daemon](http://www.avahi.org/) and configure it to advertise whichever service you'd like to connect to connect to, for example, if you're connecting via SSH, you'll need to do something like [this](https://superuser.com/a/108424/287541).

In Cocoa, you can use [`NSNetServiceBrowser`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNetServiceBrowser_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNetServiceBrowser/scheduleInRunLoop:forMode:) to find the advertised service.

## Possible MAC Address solution

Alternatively, if Avahi-daemon is not an option, you may be able to use the MAC address. I will not go into the specifics in Objective-C, just a high-level overview using the command-line.

In terminal, type `ping 255.255.255.255`. You will get back ping packets from every device on the local network. For each IP address, send an individual ping e.g. `ping -c 1 192.168.x.x`. Then, type `arp -a`. You will see the MAC address for each IP on the local network. From here, you can perhaps use your MAC address filter to find Raspberry Pis.

---

Why does this work? Well, the first command `ping 255.255.255.255` sends a ping in an IP packet to the 'broadcast' address, which means all machines on the local network respond. When you ping the individual IP addresses, the low-level networking stack uses [ARP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_Resolution_Protocol) to find the MAC address of the IP to directly send a ping to it. In doing so, the ARP tables on the local machine are updated with the cached values.

Maybe you can use this method in your app to discover local Raspberry Pis.